# label value wont echo when submitting?

Tags: php

i try getting the value of my label but it end up with nothing, I don't know what is wrong with my code? I got an error message saying " Undefined index: l_id" can anyone help me solve this.
here's my code below.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
  $itemName = $_POST['l_id'];  
  echo $itemName; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the html

Comment: What is label?. You can get values of HTML form elements with $_POST.

Comment: use !empty instead of isset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of the isset construct for your `$_POST['l_id']` too

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['l_id']))
    {
    $itemName = $_POST['l_id'];
    echo $itemName;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "I missed sending the label id from my form, let me go check my <form> code";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you checking for "add" or "l_id"?

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['l_id'])) {
  $itemName = $_POST['l_id'];  
  echo $itemName; 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

dear you set name attribute on label the form is not pass the label value.

try to using any element like input hidden, textbox,texarea instead of label tag.

Answer (score 0):

please check `l_id` is coming form add page.
I am 100 % sure 'l_id' is not coming form add page. your code is 100 % file.

You need to check all posts field are coming form add page. please check posts fields using print_r function
try below code :

```
<?php 
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($_POST);

if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
  $itemName = $_POST['l_id'];  
  echo $itemName; 
} 
?>
```